# Post photo to facebook page with graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I will upload a photo to my page as a page admin. If I use graph explorer it post photo with my account. For example I'm `masterweblab` on facebook and a page called `PAGEMWL`. I want upload photo on `PAGEMWL's` timeline as `PAGEMWL`. Can you help me?

Update:

When i try to use my app token and get access token to post field facebook return me an error like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) User must have accepted TOS", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

Comment: when i post only a text-message it work. My message was post as a page

Comment: Never seen that error before. Looks like a problem with your account or page that has violated TOS before and needs to be resolved first. Posting a photo as the page is almost identical to posting as an individual, just use the correct access token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are uploading the photo with a *page token* rather than a *user token*.

Please [refer to the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#page_access_tokens) for more information.